# nohup jupyter notebook on remote server - closed browser, is the output still there?

Tags: python, output, jupyter-notebook, remote-server, nohup

I am running a jupyter noteboook on AWS EC2 via

```
nohup jupyter notebook
```

Unfortunately my notebook went off, but when I reopen it, the notebook says:

```
kernel connected
```

I have a few `print()` commands in the script to see how the program is progressing. However th se has stopped (is by design of the jupyter notebook and cannot be changed yet). However, I wonder is there a way to check the progress of my program now? is it even still running giving me an output?

I have assigned the results to a variable and also at the end of long-running loop a command to export to csv...